# How can I run a shell script file.sh in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a simple script file test.sh as follow at location /Users/my_user/scripts/:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /Users/my_user/my_folder
```

I just want to run this script file in rust. I tried the following code but i don't understand the correct syntax:

```
use std::process::Command;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    Command::new("sh")
        .current_dir("/Users/my_user/scripts/test.sh")
        .spawn()
        .expect("sh command failed to start");
}
```

Do you have any idea? May be I am confused with Command logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. If you look at the Rust docs at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html, it's arg instead of current_dir that makes sense for your use case since you want to pass arguments to the sh command (which works with -C).

```
    Command::new("sh")
        .arg("-C")
        .arg("/Users/my_user/scripts/test.sh")
        .spawn()
        .expect("sh command failed to start");
```